# How to check for undefined behavior when casting double to int

Tags: c, casting, floating-point

Suppose we want to cast a `double` value `x` to an `int`:

```
  double x;
  ...
  int n = (int)x;
```

This is perfectly fine unless `x` happens to be outside the range of `int`. In that case we get undefined behavior (C17, 6.3.1.4-1):

> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than _Bool, the
> fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part
> cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.

**Which is the correct portable check on `x` that will allow conversion of the widest possible range of values while ensuring no undefined behavior is invoked?**

My quick guess would be the following, but I am not sure it is correct (hence the question):

```
  if(x > ((double)INT_MIN)-1.0 && x < ((double)INT_MAX)+1.0)
  {
    int n = (int)x;
    ...
  }
  else
    // Error: out of range
```

Comment: For `double` variables, that looks feasible — there are enough bits in a 64-bit `double` to represent every 32-bit integer accurately.  It's much more debatable for a 32-bit `float`, where there are only 23 bits available for the mantissa, so values outside the range ±2²³ cannot be represented accurately.  You would still get an answer, but you couldn't generate every 32-bit integer value from a `float` variable.

Comment: @nielsen, better as `x - ((double)INT_MIN) > -1.0 && x < ((double)(INT_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0` to form the limits without rounding error.